# PHP require_once not getting a variable

Tags: php, require

I'm trying to get a require_once to work, so I can use a variable content from my bootstrap file. I currently have the following file structure:

(folder) lib

(folder) templates

(file) bootstrap.php

On my bootstrap.php file I have the following array:

```
$config = array(
"db" => array(
    "db" => array(
        "dbname" => "name",
        "username" => "user",
        "password" => "pass",
        "host" => "localhost"
    ),
),
"paths" => array(
    "resources" => "/src",
)
);
```

On my lib folder I have the following 2 files:

Database.php 
User.php

Both of these are classes. In my User.php file I want to make use of the array defined in the bootstrap.php file, so I'm doing

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';
```

where **DIR** is the current folder, and then down a level to where boostrap.php is located. But when I make the folowing call:

```
var_dump( $config );
```

I get:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: config in ...\src\lib\User.php on line 37
NULL
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For debugging, I would try echoing something in bootstrap.php. If the text does not show up, the file is not being included properly. If it does show up, perhaps the variable gets unset or goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure but try this. EDITED

```
require_once('./../bootstrap.php');
```

or

```
require('./../bootstrap.php');
```

instead of this

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';
```

Comment: @MaritzaGuerreiro now i think it will work. Edited :)

Comment: @MaritzaGuerreiro add an extra dot and slash to indicate the current directory :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `include(file.php);` or `include_once(file.php);` instead.

Comment: Make sure the path is the correct one and that the file exists, try this `require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php' or die('Can't get file');` if it gives you the error you'll have to check the path

Comment: PHP should already die if the file cannot be included. Isn't that is the difference between `include` and `require`?

Comment: Just to double check, this way will die 100% sure if cannot get the file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the behaviour on UNIX systems but on Windows *DIR* outputs something line C:\Apache24\htdocs. Notice the back slashes there. That s not gonna work with file names unless you use *DIR* . "..\libs\User.php"

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for require and require_once are relative to the script file being invoked by your php runtime. So if User.php is being required elsewhere (by your root index.php for example) the path being supplied to your require statement needs to be relative to index.php, regardless of which file your require statement is in.

If you look at how php frameworks deal with this problem, they typically setup some global APP_PATH variable in the bootstrap sequence (which is an absolute path to the project on disk).

That way, wherever you need to require something, you would base the path off of APP_PATH.